# JQuery Datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to get a date picker working and I am really struggling with my limited javascript knowledge. I have been basing this on [this tutorial](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html).

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datePicker.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
 $(function()    
 {    
  $('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
 });    
</script>
```

...

```
<input name="oDate" id="oDate" class="date-pick" />
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: can you post the html as well

Comment: what are you trying to do?  what is the issue?

Comment: This brings up a bit next to the input box saying "Choose Date", however when I click this nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure there are no syntax errors or anything that would prevent the JS from running?

Comment: As far as I can tell. I have tried running it in Firefox (well, IceWeasel) with noScript turned off and Chrome

Comment: Are you also including the relevant CSS? If you could provide a link to the page where it is not working I could help you more but I can guarantee that the examples as given work for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would suggest you [take a look at the regular jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to get a standard out of the box datepicker working.  Start by simply using the exact code you see here and then tweak (step by step) as necessary.  There are tons of example for all different use cases and good documentation

Comment: Thanks, I will try this way, I can't get anything to work using the Kelvin Luck one. Even if its copied stright out of the tutorial!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried below configuration and it's working fine on my local host -

Browser Tested - Mozilla Firefox version 3.6.10

I have xampp package installed.

I am including the html file that i have used for testing -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datePicker.js"></script>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="datePicker.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
 $(function()    
 {    
  $('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
  //$('.date-pick').dpSetEndDate('01/01/2010');
 });    
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input name="oDate" id="oDate" class="date-pick" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Does this mean that it is a configuration issue? if so what do I need to check is correctly configured?

Comment: you are testing on which operating system and which browser ?

Comment: I am using debian and I have tested with firefox, iceweasel and chrome and getting nothing each time.

Comment: just install firebug ( an addon for mozilla) in your firefox browser. Just check in firebug's console that are you getting any js errors.

Comment: On the scripts tab in firebug, there are no scripts for that page

Comment: Have you tried checking console (first tab) in firebug ? Because if the plugin js file is not loading then it will show error something like this .datepicker is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have an `input` tag like so in your HTML `body`:

```
<input name="date" id="date" class="date-pick" />
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that off my post. Editing to include this.

Comment: Have you included this in a `<form>`?

Comment: And also make sure you've included the `id` attribute with the same name as the `name` attribute.

Comment: Yes - <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">

Answer (score 0):

Please check if browser java script is turned off

Comment: Don't have this code any more. Was fixed by using jquery ui datepicker originally, but now we are using <input type="date" ... Thanks anyway though :)